# Automate Data Frame Element Division

Tags: r, automation

I have a [dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xitde.png), from which I want to obtain percent treated from the dataset // where % treated = Treated / Total visits

eg. % treated Acute Maxillary Sinusitis = 93470/93470 = 100%

```
dput(droplevels(head(magma)))

structure(list(DIAG_CODE_1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("4610 SINUSITIS MAXILLARY ACUT", "4619 SINUSITIS ACUTE UNSP"
), class = "factor"), GENDER = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = "FEMALE", class = "factor"), AGE = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "0-2", class = "factor"), Mention_DRGU = c(5460L, 
5460L, 17790L, 17790L, 9400L, 9400L), treatment_status = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Total visits", "Treated"), class = "factor"), 
    diag_class_1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Acute sinusitis", class = "factor"), 
    year = c(2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2008L, 2008L)), .Names = c("DIAG_CODE_1", 
"GENDER", "AGE", "Mention_DRGU", "treatment_status", "diag_class_1", 
"year"), row.names = c(1285L, 1286L, 1407L, 1410L, 1408L, 1411L
), class = "data.frame")
```

However with 432 rows, it's possible I could calculate that all manually but that would be incredibly time consuming. Isn't that what computers are for :p. If you guys could help me find ways to automate tasks within R that would be greatly appreciated.

Is there a way that R could create a resulting dataframe that would tell me the DIAG_CODE_1, GENDER, AGE, % treated, and the year? I've created (in Excel) what I want the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEI1O.png) to look like  so you guys can see what I mean.

[image: output]

I will be doing this sort of calculation for other respiratory diseases, so I'm looking to learn now that way I can make my life easier in the long run.

Comment: @akrun I've put some dput output (hopefully properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

 magma %>% 
       spread(treatment_status, Mention_DRGU) %>%
       mutate(PercentageTreated=100*(Treated/`Total visits`)) %>% 
       select(-diag_class_1, -`Total visits`, -Treated)
 #                    DIAG_CODE_1 GENDER AGE year PercentageTreated
 #1 4610 SINUSITIS MAXILLARY ACUT FEMALE 0-2 2007               100
 #2     4619 SINUSITIS ACUTE UNSP FEMALE 0-2 2007               100
 #3     4619 SINUSITIS ACUTE UNSP FEMALE 0-2 2008               100
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Can you recommend any resources to me that would be help me understand the dplyr and tidyr packages?

Comment: These packages are still new.  So, I am not sure whether there are lots of resources available.  There is a R-day training at NYC on 15th. http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/07/08/r-day-at-strata-nyc/ I would search in `stackoverflow` for tags related to `dplyr/tidyr` .

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
magma2<-reshape(magma, idvar = c("DIAG_CODE_1","GENDER","AGE","diag_class_1","year"), timevar = "treatment_status", direction = "wide")

colnames(magma2)<-c("DIAG_CODE_1","GENDER","AGE","diag_class_1","year","Treated","TotVisits")

magma2$PercentageTreated<-as.numeric(as.character(magma2$Treated))/as.numeric(as.character(magma2$TotVisits))

head(magma2)
```

Comment: what are the errors? in absence of reproducible code, I cannot verify.

Comment: Before it was the names.  You fixed that, but now it's with the factor division `magma2$Treated/magma2$TotVisits`.  It's because the colnames are on the wrong columns

Comment: @ujjwal I think your second line is problematic.  You have 8 variables in the dataset and you naming only 6.

Comment: @ujjwal No problem +1.  Now it looks like you have 7 variables.  Have you changed your first line?

Comment: @akrun: the code if fine now. values of `Mention_DRGU` are now in`Treated` & `TotVisits`. hence only 7 columns.

Comment: @ujjwal I noticed that you updated with `diag_class_1` in the `idvar`.  Looks good now.